# qemu failed in loadvm while the guest system is windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, qemu

The guest system is in Windows XP and in the monitor.

First I `run savevm` test which looks ok

Then i `run loadvm`, the system xp halted, all i can do is `run system_reset` in the monitor to restart the xp system.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found: using `-rtc base=localtime,clock=vm`, I can restore it. I think that the sudden jump in clock time is what freezes the OS.

Note that you can then adjust the clock inside the guest if needed.

Comment: Works great after testing. Guess I added that bounty a bit fast.

Comment: Also worked on my Windows 7 VM: I was able to resume and the screen loads, but the VM did not respond to input (though with some debugging I could see that the emulated hardware was functioning)

Comment: I still have the same problem when I am using qemu with gdb attached.